# How do I catch InputMismatchException for doubles a, b, and c in this code?

Tags: java, calculator, inputmismatchexception

So I made a calculator that solves the quadratic formula, but I want the program to throw an exception when the variables a, b, or c aren't valid double numbers. However, I can't figure out how to get the variables into the equations that I want them to be in, so here is the code.

I don't know what background to put, I'm really new to java programming and I couldn't find answers to my specific problem anywhere else.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); //scanner

    short repeat = 1;
    while (repeat == 1) {

        System.out.println("Enter your equation by entering a, b, and c."); //introduction
        System.out.println("Press enter evey time you enter a number.");

        try {
            double a = input.nextDouble();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("That's not a valid number.");
        }

        double b = input.nextDouble();
        double c = input.nextDouble();

        double answer1 = ( (-b) + Math.sqrt( Math.pow(b, 2) - (4*a*c) ) ) / (2*a); //answers
        double answer2 = ( (-b) - Math.sqrt( Math.pow(b, 2) - (4*a*c) ) ) / (2*a);

        System.out.println("Your answers are: " + answer1 + " and " + answer2);

        System.out.println("Would you like to calculate more numbers? 1 for yes, 0 for no: ");
        repeat = input.nextShort();

    }

input.close();

}
```

I wanted the try/catch thing to work and for it to output a value that can be used in the equations, but the equations don't register the variable a. How would I go about doing the try/catch or any other method of displaying an error message?

Comment: If the next word is not a `double` it won't be read so every other attempt will fail. You can use `input.nextLine()` to read the whole line.

Comment: What do you define as an invalid double number? You will automatically throw that exception if you enter something that is not a number. Furthermore, you could also use ifs to manually throw it if you don't like the number. Ex) `if (a < 1) throw new InputMismatchException();`. Also, you may want to consider putting the two lines after the `catch` into your `try` block as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); //scanner

    short repeat = 1;
    while (repeat == 1) {


        System.out.println("Enter your equation by entering a, b, and c."); //introduction
        System.out.println("Press enter evey time you enter a number.");

        try {
            double a = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());
            double b = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());
            double c = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());

            double answer1 = ( (-b) + Math.sqrt( Math.pow(b, 2) - (4*a*c) ) ) / (2*a); //answers
            double answer2 = ( (-b) - Math.sqrt( Math.pow(b, 2) - (4*a*c) ) ) / (2*a);

            System.out.println("Your answers are: " + answer1 + " and " + answer2);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("That's not a valid number.");
        }



        System.out.println("Would you like to calculate more numbers? 1 for yes, 0 for no: ");
        repeat = Short.parseShort(input.nextLine());

    }
    input.close();

}
```

- You have initalize the repeat variable to 1 and not to 0, since the program will not enter the while loop otherways.
- You need to put your calculations for answer1 and answer2 in the try-catch-block too, because if the user enters an invalid value, the result shouldn't get calculated.
- You should use only one Scanner instance, so you mustn't instance it in the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I was using an older version of my code which I forgot to update so all of the errors that I made are gone except for the try/catch system. I understand that you can just put everything into the block!

Comment: I have a question, why use double a = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine()); instead of double a = input.nextDouble(); ? Just wondering!

Comment: With `input.nextDouble()` it depends on your region if , or . is used as decimal point. (but you can change the `Locale`-object of the scanner or the comma delimiter), and `parseDouble()` uses . as decimal point always.  You can use `.nextLine()` as well as `.nextDouble()`/`.nextShort()`, but you mustn't mix them.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--) `Scanner` throws `InputMismatchException` if the next value is not a valid double value, so you should not take care of it manually.

But if you want to display a message when an exception occurs, you should catch it with try-catch block and do what you want to do.

> the equations don't register the variable a

This happens because `a` is part of the "try" block scope. Once you exit this block, the variable is gone.

What you probably want to do is:

```
 double a; //declaring variable a (main() method scope)
 try {
     a = input.nextDouble(); //assigning a new value
 }
 catch (InputMismatchException e) {
     System.out.println("That's not a valid number.");
     throw e; //notice, the exception is still thrown after the message is printed
 }
```

So now `a` is in the `main` method's scope and you can use it after the try-catch block.